# How to insert values into an array alphabetically?

Tags: c++

I need the insert function to take an argument and then add it to a list, but instead of it simply adding it to the end, it finds the alphabetical position and adds it there. So, if the array was {1, 3, 4} and we were adding 2 to the array, it would find the index to add it, which would be index 1, shift all of the index past that insertion point down. However, I simply cannot for the life of me figure out how to write the logic behind it.

Assume the array isn't full and there is extra space to move the items down in the array.

I can't use another array to copy values or anything like that. I NEED to shift the values down the array and insert the value at the proper point all within the insertion function.

```
/*************************************
 * insert()
 *************************************/
bool people::insert(person arg)
{
    person temp;
    int i, value, insertionPoint;

    // Check to see if array is full

    cout << "Array size is " << len << endl;

    if (len >= LIST_SIZE)
    {
        cout << "Array null" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Adds item if array is empty.
    if (len == 0)
    {
        cout << "FIRST VALUE ADDED which is: " << arg.firstName << endl;
        map[0] = arg;
    }

    // Find Insertion Point

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(arg < map[i])
        {
            insertionPoint = i;
        }
        else
        {
            insertionPoint = len;
        }
    }

    for (i = insertionPoint; value > insertionPoint; value--)
    {
        map[value] = map[value - 1];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: To move the elements down, you can loop through.  Start at the end, and move it.  Then go backwards, toward the point where you need to free up the space, moving one element at a time forward.  When the loop is done, there's a gap ready to hold the element you'd like to insert.

Comment: If they are simple bytes (trivial values or types, just data, no behavior, no member functions, etc.), you can use memmove().

Comment: What is `map` declared as?  To find the insertion point, `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` can be used.  Actually, if you were to use C++ fully, this is a 3 line program of `std::lower_bound`, `std::copy`, and then an insertion of the value inside the array where `lower_bound` indicates.

Comment: If you're allowed to use the standard library, you could simply use [`std::copy_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward)...

Comment: Yeah, `copy_backeards`.  But the idea still holds -- this is a 3 line function with no loops required, but only *if* the OP is allowed to use C++ to its fullest.

Comment: map is an array of person objects. Also, i can't use memmove() or anything else. The goal is to write out the logic myself.

Comment: @J.J. If you can't use those functions, then please state in the question what you *can* use.  Otherwise you have people putting together a (correct) answer, but for some reason doesn't fit your requirements.  By default, the answer will be valid C++ unless we see the requirements up front.

Answer (score 3):

You have to start at the tail of the list. It looks like you have map[] as your array and len as the current number of elements.

So let's look at some code. You're loop to find the insertion point is flawed. Aside from a binary search being faster:

```
int insertionPoint = len;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if(arg < map[i])
    {
        insertionPoint = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

That's much cleaner. There's no reason to continue to search once you find the insertion point.

Now you have insertionPoint set, so you need to make room. You want to move all pointers from [insertionPoint] to [len-1] up one point, but if you start at [insertionPoint], you'll step all over the rest.

So you do it backwards:

```
for (int index = len; index > insertionPoint; --index) {
    map[index] = map[index - 1];
}
```

At that point, you can then:

```
map[insertionPoint] = arg;
++len;
```

---

I'm adding this as the OP has said he's disallowed from using break. I don't know why that would be, but okay.

```
int insertionPoint = 0;
while (insertionPoint < len && arg < map[insertionPoint]) {
    ++insertionPoint;
}
```

This loop won't go past the end. If we find ourselves off the end, `insertionPoint` will become equal to `len`, which is what it needs to be. But the loop stops when it should.

Comment: I can't use break, so what would be an alternative to using the break statement? Also, does this code keep in mind that while scanning through the array, we might not find a value that is lower than the inserted value? For example, {1,2,3} and we're inserting 4. How do we code for getting to the endof the array and not finding an insertion point?

Comment: @J.J. The second half of your question is handled by initializing insertionPoint to the end of the array from the beginning. But I'll update my answer with a solution that doesn't rely on break.